# Replicate selection in Gimp

Tags: gimp

I'm trying to use gimp for pixel art. In a tutorial I saw someone making a selection in photoshop and then use the selection to draw. Not sure if I explain it right, so I clipped a couple of seconds from youtube where you can see what I mean.

https://www.youtube.com/clip/UgkxNpTY0RibapZUFHP5WnJl0AJx7x7rLzRl

Now I wonder how I would do this in Gimp

This would save me a lot of time so if anyone could tell me how to do this I would be very glad. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He doesn't actually draw with the selection, he stretches the selected area higher. The layer contains only 2 colored pixels which are stretched higher. He operates with keyboard shortcuts to be fast.

An example in GIMP:

[image]

The image is 50 x 50 pixels. It has 2 layers. The bottom layer contains large blue and red dots. The top layer has only 2 single pixel red dots above the big blue dot.

The small red dots are selected with the rectangular selection tool:

[image]

The content of the selected area is stretched higher with the scale tool. GIMP leaves the result floating, so you can still decide do you want to continue the scaling, anchor it to the top layer where you started or do you want a totally new layer:

[image]

To get pixel perfect result with no antialias blur you must select in the scaling tool options Interpolation = None.

Comment: Very cool! Thank you 